# Remove text from string in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string and i need to remove few characters like this

```
text='abcd2345'
string = text.replace("cd", "") 

print(string)
ab2345
```

I need to remove the following two numbers in the string without specifying. how do i achieve it.

Output should be

```
ab45
```

Comment: Use a regular expression with `re.sub()`

Comment: Those are not the preceding 2 numbers, they're the following 2 numbers.

Comment: i dont want to specify numbers, i want to specify text and it should remove following two numbers..

Comment: and if there's not two *following* numbers as @Barmar points out... (eg none or just one...) - what happens then?

Comment: The rudimentary way would be `i = string.find('cd')` / `string = string[:i]+string[i+4:]`.

Comment: `re.sub("cd\d{2}", "", text)`

Comment: That's why you use a regular expression. It will match any 2 digits.

Comment: If you don't understand, start by reading the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: @Barmar https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html is also good

Comment: @d.b Barbar , thanks a=re.sub("USDT\d{2}", "", text)
 this is working for me as expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to specify a string then you can use regex:

```
import re

text = 'abcd2345'
string = re.sub('cd\d{2}', '', text)
```

Output:

```
'ab45'
```

### How does it work?

It matches the string `cd` and any two numbers with the help of `\d{2}` followed by the string.

Comment: No, i want to specify the string and remove the next two numbers from the specified string..

Comment: @Kowsi OK, I have added the regex method as well. You can check it out now!